# Dynamically generate field value

Tags: mysql

Is there any way, in MySQL, to dynamically generate a field value?  For example a field that stamps the exact date and time that a row was inserted.

You could just get the interface to do it (i.e. PHP) but in a case where you have more than one handler it would be safer if I could get MySQL to do it independently.

Comment: P.S.  I know MySQL has a TIMESTAMP facility but that is just an example.  There have been other scenarios where I've wanted to dynamically generate a field value - just can't think of one now!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL `TIMESTAMP` data type has a special default called `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` that does this.

Read all about it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html

EDIT:
For the more generic case, use a trigger. You can set the value on an insert using a `BEFORE INSERT` triggers, and likewise you can set the value on updates using a separate `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Yeah, I knew about that.  Sorry, I used a bad example in my question.